Data is missing after order by a column
I have to generate a graphic of median_rate by year of measles contamination. I noticed the data goes missing after this line:
filtered_data['state'] = pd.Categorical(filtered_data['state'], categories=median_rates.index[median_rates.index <= 1963], ordered=True)

My code:
import pandas as pd
import plotnine as pn


# Lê a base de dados
us_contagious_diseases = pd.read_csv("us_contagious_diseases.csv")

#Seleciona a doença
the_disease = "Measles"

# Filtrando os dados e criando uma cópia. A condição de filtragem é não ser do Havaí ou do Alasca e ser dados de sarampo
filtered_data = us_contagious_diseases[~us_contagious_diseases['state'].isin(["Hawaii", "Alaska"]) & (us_contagious_diseases['disease'] == the_disease)].copy()

# Calculando a taxa
filtered_data['rate'] = (filtered_data['count'] / filtered_data['population'] * 10000 * 52 / filtered_data['weeks_reporting'])
#print(filtered_data['state'])

# Calcula a mediana da coluna 'rate' para cada ano (agrupado por filtered_data.groupby('year'))
median_rates = filtered_data.groupby('year')['rate'].median()
print(filtered_data['state'])

# Reordenando os estados com base na taxa
filtered_data['state'] = pd.Categorical(filtered_data['state'], categories=median_rates.index[median_rates.index <= 1963], ordered=True)
print(filtered_data['state'])

# Filtrando para os dados da Califórnia e fazendo uma cópia
dat_ca = filtered_data[(filtered_data['state'] == "California") & filtered_data['rate'].notnull()].copy()
print(dat_ca)

# Criando o gráfico
pn.ggplot(dat_ca, pn.aes(x='year', y='rate')) + pn.geom_line() + pn.ylab("Cases per 10,000") + pn.geom_vline(xintercept=1963, color="blue")

Result:

Information:

Dataset is available in https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/datasets.html
I have to use ggplot in Python


Your error here is that you're using the median rates index, which is in years, to categorize the states column. If you want to make the state column a categorical variable and only keep data prior to 1963, you should change the problem causing line to this:
filtered_data = filtered_data[filtered_data['year'] <= 1963].copy()

filtered_data['state'] = pd.Categorical(filtered_data['state'], ordered=True)

